# How to ensure JavaScript will run in AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, extjs, innerhtml

I have an `Ext.Ajax.request` call that returns a `.html` file. Even when put into an `onReady` function, the `JavaScript` in the file is still not recognized. Only when I force the page to loop again is it loaded.

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: URL,
        method: 'GET',
        success: function(response) { 
            div.innerHTML=response.responseText;
        },
        failure: function(response){
            div.innerHTML="";
        }
    });
```

My question is how do I return `JavaScript` in an `AJAX` call that is guaranteed to run after the page is loaded?

Comment: You will need to show more of your code (all of the ajax call) for us to advise to do anything other than make wild guesses at what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The AJAX function in jQuery has some different properties you can call as promises for when the request is done, always etc.

Try working with the code below:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/path/to/file',
    type: 'default GET (Other values: POST)',
    dataType: 'default: Intelligent Guess (Other values: xml, json, script, or html)',
    data: {param1: 'value1'},
})
.done(function() {
    console.log("success");
})
.fail(function() {
    console.log("error");
})
.always(function() {
    console.log("complete");
});
```